# Porque "submetemos" um formulário? É o verbo errado?

Tags: uso-de-palavras

O verbo submeter é usado na frase `submeter um formulário`.

Mas nenhum dos seus [significados](http://priberam.pt/dlpo/submeter) parece aplicar-se nessa frase:

> verbo transitivo
>
> 1. Pôr debaixo de.
> 2. Tornar dependente.
> 3. Sujeitar; obrigar; subjugar.
>
> verbo pronominal
>
> 4. Fazer submissão.
> 5. Humilhar-se.
>
> "submeter", in Dicionário Priberam da Língua Portuguesa [em linha], 2008-2013, http://priberam.pt/dlpo/submeter [consultado em 18-09-2015].

Será um *falso-amigo*, um mau uso acidentalmente importado do inglês ou outra língua?
Ou será que alguma das definições se aplica?

Comment: Submeter deve ser uma importação de "submit". Em Portugal costumavamos usar "Enviar o formulário".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Talvez fosse melhor, dependendo do contexto, dizer *entregar um formulário*, mas *submeter um formulário* não está errado. Do Dicionário da Academia das Ciências de Lisboa, *submeter*, entrada 5:

> Levar alguma coisa à apreciação de alguém, para que se faça um julgamento ou se tome uma decisão. *Submeti a proposta à administração. O governo submeteu a lei a apreciação.*

Se for um formulário apenas com os nossos dados para ficarem em base de dados, *submeter* poderá ser excessivo. Aquilo não vai ser apreciado por ninguém. Daí poder ser melhor dizer *entregar* ou, como sugerido pelo Jorge B, *enviar* se for online. Mesmo quando seja um formulário com um pedido qualquer (concessão de bolsa de estudo, aceitação como membro de uma organização) talvez faça mais sentido dizer *entreguei o formulário* e *submeti o o pedido*. Mas *submeter o formulário* seria ainda assim uma extensão do significado de *submeter o pedido*.

Comment: No caso de um formulário online poderia ser "Enviei o formulário" em vez de *entreguei*, porque acho que *entregar* reflete mais o ato de ir *entregar* alguma coisa.

Comment: Sim, acho que enviar é melhor se for online.

Answer (score 3):

Em **ptBR** não é uso corrente "submeter um formulário".  Nós preenchemos um formulário e o submetemos a apreciação de alguma autoridade.  Mesmo assim, seria mais comum nâo usar o verbo "submeter", como por exemplo: "Preenchi o formulário e ele foi encaminhado à diretoria da empresa para apreciação." ou "Preenchi o formulário e o enviei à diretoria..."

Por outro lado, usamos "submeter alguma coisa à apreciação de alguém". É de uso formal.

- "Não senhor, ainda não temos uma resposta. Seu requerimento ainda vai ser **submetido à apreciação da diretoria.**" Então ao chegar em casa, te perguntam: "Qual foi a resposta que deram?"  E tu respondes em português coloquial: "Nenhuma, a diretoria ainda nem leu o requerimento."

Comment: E no caso dos formulários online? Era nesses que eu tinha pensado inicialmente.

Comment: @ANeves Não conheço nada alem do que citei acima: "enviar", "encaminhar".

Answer (score 3):

Também usamos o verbo submeter com o sentido de realizar submissão ou enviar para avaliação, principalmente em contexto acadêmico ou profissional.

- *"Submeti um projeto para aquele edital mas creio que não foi avaliado ainda."*
- *"Vocês terão um prazo de 15 dias corridos para submeter o trabalho.*"

Não sei se é um neologismo do submit, mas é bem usado.