# Qual seria a tradução do termo "commit" para o português?

Tags: tradução

Na ferramenta de versionamento de arquivos git, cada alteração salva é chama de *commit*, por exemplo, a frase "preciso *commitar* as alterações" significa mais ou menos "salvar as alterações", porém *commitar* não é exatamente salvar, pois o arquivo já está salvo localmente na memória da máquina, o *commit* insere apenas aquele estágio do arquivo na estrutura de versionamento do git.

No tradutor Google a tradução principal mais próxima seria "cometer", mas não vejo, nesse contexto, como uma boa tradução, cometer o que?

Então qual seria a melhor tradução para essa palavra no cenário da programação?

Comment: Eu diria guardar as alterações em vez de cometer-las como se fossem um delito ou salvá-las como se fossem uma alma, mas não tenho um nome que corresponda a **um** *commit*.

Comment: Confirmar as alterações? Ou transportar as alterações. Commit tem a idea de transporte, "carry out"..

Comment: Já existe esta [pergunta sobre "how to translate 'committed' in technical documentation"](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/1182/how-to-translate-committed-to-portuguese-in-a-technical-documentation). Parece-me que é basicamente a mesma coisa. Vê lá.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Dado que *commit* significa "guardar num repositório", uma boa opção talvez seja **depositar**, por outro lado, o substantivo *registro* é mais claro que "depósito", favorecendo **registrar**, mas há várias possibilidades:

- **depositar**, entregar
- **registrar**, consignar
- **submeter**, despachar, enviar
- transferir
- armazenar, guardar, salvar (no repositório)

Em que considerei sugestões do [WordReference](https://www.wordreference.com/enpt/commit), dicionários de português e o [significado](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/commit) relevante (e sinônimos) de *commit*.

Comment: Com base na documentação <https://git-scm.com/docs/git-commit>, *registrar [alterações]* parece-me mais adequado.

Comment: @ValdeirPsr Sim, numa segunda olhada, também prefiro registrar agora, inclusive pela razão que adicionei à resposta (penso que "registro" é melhor que "depósito" para o substantivo).

Comment: Note que commit tb é muito usaod em banco de dados. Um termo que se refere que a transação foi enviada ao banco de dados. Geralmente em TI nós usamos neologismos como "Comita o build por favor. Ontem eu comitei as alterações no código. O comit falhou e tivemos que dar um rollback na transação!

Comment: @jean Sim, eu também certamente usaria "dar um commit" ao invés de tentar traduzir (a menos que, por exemplo, usasse um ambiente ou programa que usa o termo traduzido). Mas acho que o commit do banco de dados é um pouco diferente do do versionamento.

Comment: @stafusa Nem tão diferentes, ambos se destinam a "persistir no servidor" um "rascunho em memória" num ambiente onde vários usuários podem estar fazendo o mesmo (e de forma assíncrona). Na verdade o git tenta implementar os mesmos princípios ACID (com diferenças nas estratégias de I e C) de um DB e o significado da palavra Commit é praticamente a mesma nos dois casos

Answer (score 0):

Depende do contexto, desta feita esta palavra pode ser traduzida nos seguintes termos, vamos a elas:
Presente: commit; na terceira pessoa: commits; passado: committed; past participle: committed; gerundio ou present participle: committing
Commit pode ser traduzido de três formas diferentes
1 - Cometer, no sentido de fazer algo ilegal, erro ou imoral.
“She committed a murder” → “Ela cometeu um crime”
Sinônimos: carry out, do, perform, perpetrate, engage in, enact, execute, effect, accomplish
2 - Comprometer-se, no sentido de se comprometer com outra pessoa por uma causa, um negócio ou qualquer ato. "They were reluctant to commit themselves to an opinion" → “Eles estavam relutantes em comprometerem-se a uma opinião”
Sinônimos: pledge, devote, apply, give, dedicate, bind, obligate"
“Local business leaders committed themselves to community projects" → “Líderes comerciais locais comprometeram-se com projetos comunitários”
Sinônimos: devout, devoted, loyal, dedicated, faithful, staunch, firm, steadfast, resolute, unwavering, sincere, wholehearted, keen, earnest, enthusiastic, zealous, passionate, ardent, fervent, motivated, driven, active, sworn, pledged;
3 – Confinar, transferir a algo, ou ainda prender alguém.
"He composed a letter but didn't commit it to paper" → “Ele compôs um carta, mas não transferiu, não passou ao papel”
"She was committed to prison for contempt of court" → “Ela foi confinada a prisão (presa)”
Sinônimos: consign, assign, send, deliver, confine
"Her husband had her committed after her eccentricity became dangerous" → “Seu marido a confinou no hospital depois que o comportamento excêntrico dela tornou-se perigoso.”
Sinônimos: hospitalize, confine, institutionalize, put away, lock away, lock up; certify

Além dos significados mencionados, acrescento que o termo em informática é usado no sentido de “aplicar”, “tornar efetivo”, em várias situações, nomeadamente, quando se faz uma transação numa base de dados.
[enter link description here](https://dicionario.reverso.net/ingles-portugues/Committee)

enter link description here